# ¿Cómo convertir lista a formato date en Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando convertir el formato de esta lista:

```py
[datetime.date(2021, 1, 19), datetime.date(2021, 1, 20), datetime.date(2021, 1, 22)]
```

A una lista `date`:

```py
[2021-01-19,2021-01-20, 2021-01-22...]
```

Estoy trabajando en **Django** y no puedo encontrar la manera de convertir esta lista al formato `date` desde `view.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar strftime(). Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import datetime

listData=[datetime.date(2021, 1, 19), datetime.date(2021, 1, 20), datetime.date(2021, 1, 22)]
newData=[d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in listData]

print(listData)
print(newData)
```

Devuelve:

```
[datetime.date(2021, 1, 19), datetime.date(2021, 1, 20), datetime.date(2021, 1, 22)]
['2021-01-19', '2021-01-20', '2021-01-22']
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! me ha servido tu solución, Saludos!

Comment: Me alegra mucho :-)